# Can I use the data() pointer from an std::array member variable before it is initialized? Gives warning

Tags: c++

I am initializing a base class (**Matrix<3,3>** in example) using the pointer to data stored in an std::array member of derived class **SelfContained**, being warned that "*Field 'vdata' is uninitialized when used here*" on doing so.

The warning makes sense, but I'm not sure the best way to avoid it... the code seems to work anyway, but I don't like to see warnings so I'm attempting to fix it.

I might be totally wrong, but it seems like std:array vdata is  allocated when used here, so the data() pointer should already be valid even though the array is uninitialized. Since I'm initializing it immediately afterwards, I'm tempted to just ignore the warning... but I'm hopeful that there's a more "correct" way...

I've iterated through this a couple times... previously the std::array was a C-style array and grabbing the pointer to it did not cause a problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<class ContainedType>
class SelfContained: public ContainedType{
public:
    typedef ContainedType Type;
    
    static constexpr size_t numel()     {   return Type::numel();}
    
    typedef std::array<double, numel()> DataArray;   //  Data Array Type
    DataArray vdata;
    
    SelfContained(DataArray arry_in): ContainedType(vdata.data()), vdata{arry_in} {} // WARNING: Field 'vdata' is uninitialized when used here
    
};


template <size_t m, size_t n>
class Matrix{
public:
    typedef double DoubleArray[n][m];   //  Data Array Type
    
    DoubleArray* pdata = NULL;        //  Pointer to data array: to be assigned on instantiation to let instance be a specified sub-array of something else.
    
    static constexpr size_t height() {return m;}
    static constexpr size_t width()  {return n;}
    static constexpr size_t numel()  {return m*n;}
    
    Matrix(double* p) noexcept : pdata{(DoubleArray*)p}{}

    // Element reference getters (mostly for internal convenience)
    template<typename ...Args>
    double& data(Args... vals){
        return get_data(*this, vals...);
    }
    template<typename ...Args>
    const double& data(Args... vals) const{
        return get_data(*this, vals...);
    }
    
    // Print Matrix
    void print() const {
        for (size_t j=0; j<height(); j++){
            for(size_t k=0;k<width(); k++){
                std::printf("%+15.7f ",data(j,k));
                //std::printf("%+4.1f ",data(j,k));
            } std::printf("\n");
        } std::printf("\n");
    }
    
private:
    
    // Helper functions for public element-reference getters ...
    // weird, but minimizes code dupication (const/non-const) by putting the guts here
    template<typename InstanceType>
    static auto get_data(InstanceType& instance, size_t row) -> decltype(instance.data(row)) {
        assert(row >= 0 && row < instance.numel());
        return (*(instance.pdata))[0][row];
    }
    template<typename InstanceType>
    static auto get_data(InstanceType& instance, size_t row, size_t col) -> decltype(instance.data(row,col)) {
        assert(col >= 0 && col < instance.width());
        assert(row >= 0 && row < instance.height());
        return (*(instance.pdata))[col][row];
    }
};

constexpr std::array<double,9> x0 = {1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    
    SelfContained<Matrix<3,3>>(x0).print();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Gives warning:
*Field 'vdata' is uninitialized when used here*

Output:

```
     +1.0000000      +0.0000000      +0.0000000 
     +0.0000000      +2.0000000      +0.0000000 
     +0.0000000      +0.0000000      +3.0000000
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What's your compiler/version? No issue with latest gcc with `-Wall`.

Comment: If you want a pointer to the underlying array structure, you should use `data()` instead of `begin()`. `begin()` returns an iterator which isn't necessarily a pointer (this might change in c++20). `data()` always returns a pointer, and communicates the intention better than `begin()`.

Comment: Reading uninitialised data is Undefined Behaviour. Also, `begin()` returns an *iterator*, not a *pointer*.

Comment: You get the warning because of the initialization order, the base class ContainedType gets initialized before "vdata". In this case you could pass arry_in to ContainedType constructor instead of vdata.

Comment: @Holt compiler is __clang_version__ "10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)"

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks, I tried that also, same warning but I'll switch it knowing that this is best practice.

Comment: @JesperJuhl will switch to data() pointer

Comment: @Gerard097 the purpose of abstracting the Matrix guts out of the array is so that it can refer to data other than a single array (an easy example would be a Matrix<2,2> stored in elements (3,4,5,6)  of a SelfContained<Matrix<8,1>>) ... passing the array instead of the pointer would get in the way of this I believe.

Comment: Then you might wanna try Composition instead of Inheritance

Comment: You should get rid of those semi-colons after your constructors (`Matrix(double* p) noexcept : pdata{(DoubleArray*)p}{};`). They don't do any harm here, but they don't do any good either (and they make it look as if you don't know what you're doing).

Comment: @Holt Just because something *compiles* does *not* mean that it is *valid*.

Comment: @TonyK, has the same not-quite-mistake at the end of `print()`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I never say that.

Comment: @Holt You said "No issue with latest gcc with -Wall". That statement is meaningless. Just because some compiler compiled it without errors/warnings with some options, means *nothing* as far as correctness goes.

Comment: @JesperJuhl My comment only says what it says, `gcc` does not show OP's behavior. It does not say that `gcc` is correct. It says that there is an inconsistency between OP's compiler and latest gcc, which in many cases (maybe not here) is at least partially useful to know.

Comment: @TonyK Goal achieved then, because I definitely don't know what I'm doing. I do like to pretend though. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, calling `vdata.begin()` before `vdata` is initialised is technically UB, even though the member function doesn't need to touch any members.

Another problem however is `(DoubleArray*)p`. Accessing though the reinterpreted pointer as if it points a `DoubleArray` has undefined behaviour when it doesn't actually point to such object.

Comment: How would `begin` get away without reading the state of the container?  It can't, so it must be UB.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Because it simply doesn't need to know any of the state. It relies solely on the address of the members, which is known at that point. But the member function call is UB regardless (as far as I know).

Comment: Can you recommend a better practice here? I was under the impression that since array members are stored contiguously casting between double[9]* and double[3][3]* through double* (because in some instances I only want to access part of the array) would be fine ... another case where it seems to be working, but I don't write in c++ often enough to recognize when I'm getting away with something I shouldn't be.

Comment: Also, is there a way to get that address without using the member function, since the address is known but the member function results in UB?

Comment: @Jeremy Use a flat 1D array as storage. Write a function to access different dimensions that are laid flat. Don't ever use C-style cast. Don't use reinterpret_cast until you have enough experience to recognise what you are allowed to reinterpret_cast.

Comment: The storage is flat currently (I think) as std::array<double,numel()>, unless I need to switch back to a C-style array? So just write a function to access instead of relying on the built-in brackets and casting for different sized arrays?

Comment: @Jeremy The storage is flat. Just use it as a flat array, rather than attempting to cast it to a multi dimensional one.

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue here is that you can't force members to be initialized before inherited values.

One possible solution is to move the data members that must be initialized first to another type, and inherit that first, which forces those inherited members to be initialized first.  This way, `vdata` is initialized before the `ContainedType` constructor is called.

Doing so makes the "is this defined behavior" discussion pointless.

```
template<class ContainedType>
class SelfContainedMembers {
public:
    typedef ContainedType Type;

    typedef std::array<double, Type::numel()> DataArray;   //  Data Array Type
    DataArray vdata;

    SelfContainedMembers(DataArray arry_in): vdata{arry_in} { }
};

template<class ContainedType>
class SelfContained: private SelfContainedMembers<ContainedType>, public ContainedType {
public:
    typedef ContainedType Type;
    typedef SelfContainedMembers<ContainedType> Members;

    static constexpr size_t numel()     {   return Type::numel();}

    typedef typename Members::DataArray DataArray;

    SelfContained(DataArray arry_in): Members{arry_in}, ContainedType{Members::vdata.data()} {};
};
```

(See [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbd81e54547ee911) and note the lack of warnings.)

Comment: This looks promising... Thank you! At some point I developed a habit of avoiding multiple inheritance like the plague, I guess it's time to push through that and learn how to do it without shooting myself in the foot. Thanks again!